# Load Images from Assets in Widget remoteView

Tags: android, remoteview

I am using the following code to load my image into Android widget `ImageView`:

```
remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget_image, R.drawable.image);
```

I have to save the image in `drawable` folder. Is it possible to save the image in assets instead and load it to `remoteView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `BitmapFactory`, you can load an image in `assets/` as a `Bitmap` from an `InputStream` provided by `AssetManager`, and then use the `RemoteViews#setImageViewBitmap()` method to set it on your widget.

For example:

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
...

try {
    InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("image.jpg");
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

    remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.widget_image, bmp);
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution :

```
 imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);
        try {
            // get input stream
            InputStream ims = getAssets().open("download.jpg");
            // load image as Drawable
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
            // set image to ImageView
            imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            return;
        }
```